# Where could PHP output which started at php://input:1 be originating from?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Today I tried to login to my wordpress instance which is running on my own server. Upon clicking *Login*, the page reported the following:

```
log=admin&pwd=passwort&wp-submit=Log+In&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&testcookie=1
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at php://input:1) in /var/www/html/wp-login.php on line 504

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at php://input:1) in /var/www/html/wp-login.php on line 520

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at php://input:1) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6225
```

My setup is as follows:

- PHP 7.0.15
- Wordpress 4.7.1
- Nginx, MySql and Wordpress running as docker instances
- Another nginx instance that coordinates the routing and redirections (e.g. http -> https)

```
        Name                      Command              State            Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wordpress_mysql_1       docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld    Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp
wordpress_nginx_1       nginx -g daemon off;           Up      127.0.0.1:44654->80/tcp
wordpress_wordpress_1   docker-entrypoint.sh php-fpm   Up      0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp
```

The thing that bothers me is the source of the output: `php://input:1`. I tried adding a `die('test');` right after the `<php` opening tag in `wp-login.php` and to my surprise, the string `'test'` appeared **AFTER** the request string.

Does someone have an idea how I could debug this or where this could possibly be coming from?

Comment: What's different today from yesterday?

Comment: *yesterday* is about 9 months ago when I set everything up. I looked at the nginx configuration files and couldn't find any alterations, same for the scripts within the containers unless I have missed something. I am not sure about external moduls, maybe those cause the error? But I am pretty sure it must be something to do with PHP. Otherwise wordpress wouldn't show this error. I just don't know where it could come from ...

Comment: What is your WordPress version?

Comment: Wordpress 4.7.1

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `auto_prepend_file` was set to `php://input` although the default value should be `NULL`. I could not find where exactly this value was altered but adding `auto_prepend_file=NULL` to `php.ini` and restarting the instances fixed this issue.